# Array of images to display

Tags: iphone, ios, arrays, uiimage

I have a sample code to display images in the gridview from the below code...but it display the same image for all the images ...the method is below..

```
- (MMGridViewCell *)gridView:(MMGridView *)gridView cellAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
MMGridViewDefaultCell *cell = [[MMGridViewDefaultCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectNull];
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d", index];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell-image.png"];
 // this needs to be change load from the array
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfCellsInGridView:(MMGridView *)gridView
{
return 64;
}
```

Now I have a array of images and need to put into that `cellAtIndex` method  but what should i do to transform into that for all the images into the array..

the array is like

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
_imageDatas = [DelegateClass mag]._imageData;
_finaImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
_finaImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i = 0; i < [_imageDatas count]; i++) {

    [_finaImages addObject:[self loadImage:i]];
}

- (UIImage *)loadImage:(int)index {
@try {
    UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[_imageDatas objectAtIndex:index]] ;

    return image;
 }
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"ImageFullScreenViewController - loadImage Exception Name = %@ Exception Reason = %@",[exception name],[exception reason]);
  }
```

How do i transform the data from the below array to the above imageView.image

Comment: Let me point out that there is an extra } on line four of your viewDidLoad, which should make it unable to compile.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
- (MMGridViewCell *)gridView:(MMGridView *)gridView cellAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
MMGridViewDefaultCell *cell = [[MMGridViewDefaultCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectNull];
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d", index];
    cell.imageView.image =[imagesArray objectAtIndex: index];
 // this needs to be change load from the array
}
```

Comment: -[ArtOfSleeping _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x88fb960
2013-03-22 15:14:32.859 Magazine[2822:17c03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ArtOfSleeping _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x88fb960'

Comment: make sure imagesArray has UIImage objects..if you are putting objects of ArtOfSleeping objects then it can cause that.

Answer (score 2):

Replace this:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell-image.png"];
```

With:

```
cell.imageView.image = (UIImage *)[_finaImages objectAtIndex:index];
```

Comment: -[ArtOfSleeping _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x88fb960
2013-03-22 15:14:32.859 Magazine[2822:17c03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ArtOfSleeping _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x88fb960'

Comment: Please `NSLog(@"%@',_finalImages);` If your above code is right. Then it'll work.

Comment: thing is images are in the url and fetching from the webservice from the imageDatas array and it shows the catch error when i am trying to run the code

Answer (score 1):

```
- (MMGridViewCell *)gridView:(MMGridView *)gridView cellAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    MMGridViewDefaultCell *cell = [[MMGridViewDefaultCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectNull];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d", index];
    // Use this
    cell.imageView.image = [self loadImage:index];
}
```